# Can I access an encrypted USB in Ubuntu VirtualBox VM?

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, encryption

I used the standard disk utility on another 2.6.x Ubuntu desktop to encrypt a USB device. Can I access this through a similar VM on a Mac OS X host?

I don't have any problems accessing normal USB devices on the VM, but when I insert the encrypted one, I get an error message saying that it can't be mounted.

Is this possible?

Comment: This doesn't solve your current problem, but in the future, consider using TrueCrypt.  It is cross-platform, so you can mount encrypted volumes on just about anything.  http://www.truecrypt.org/

Answer (score 1):

I believe your encrypted partitions will have been set up with dm-crypt. As far as I know, its tied to Linux.

Comment: yeah i read that i would have to have another 2.6.x kernel to decrrypt it, but that is what my VM is. Do you think this should be possible through the Mac os x host?